# Excel power query average of all values in a column

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a table in power query and I want to create a new column that displays the average of all values of another referenced column. Any idea how to achieve this? So for example the home.goaldFor column i want to add-up all values and devide by the number of values.

i have tried multiple ways, including this one:

```
Avg = List.Average(
        Table.SelectColumns(
        #"ENG - Premier League",
        [home.goalsFor],
        0
    )
)
```

But that's giving me the error:
Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.

Anyone any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `#"ENG - Premier League"` the name of the current step based on the error you're getting.

Try this instead:

```
Avg = List.Average(#"Previous Step Name"[home.goalsFor])
```